# Is wcf web service.close needed

Tags: .net, wcf

I have some code shown below, which appears to work as needed.  My question is - is it necessary to have a webservice.close?  This will go out of scope at the end of the sub.  The main reason I ask is the wsClient in finally gets a code warning,

Variable 'wsClient' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

The best outcome would probably be to restructure and keep the .close and get rid of the warning.

```
    Dim wsClient As wsGates.ConsoleClient

    Try
        wsClient = New wsGates.ConsoleClient
        Dim wsRet As wsGates.clsReturn

        wsRet = wsClient.Phase1Validate("15024")
    Catch

    Finally
        If wsClient IsNot Nothing Then wsClient.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not close it, the underlying channel may remain open. While this may eventually be closed when the object is GC'd or your application exits, it is best to close it to release resources as soon as possible.

Rather than using a `Try` statement, I would recommend a `Using`:

```
Using wsClient As New wsGates.ConsoleClient
    Dim wsRet As wsGates.clsReturn

    wsRet = wsClient.Phase1Validate("15024")
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

not required to close wsClient because its life only on that method only. After that method execute it auto manically destroy object.

Comment: .Net objects are not automatically destroyed on method exit. They are garbage collected later at some arbitrary time.